# Regex replace XML tag only (not content)

Tags: regex

First of all, I know that you shouldn't try to use regex to modify XML, this is a special case where I have to do that anyway and not use a parser.

I want this:

```
<nicetag_A-B>Teststring X-Y</nicetag_A-B>
```

To look like this:

```
<nicetag_>Teststring X-Y</nicetag_>
```

In short, I want to remove [any letter]-[any-letter] but only from the tag, not the actual content inside.

This is my regex so far:

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, @"(<.*?[a-zA-Z])\-([a-zA-Z].*?>)", "$1$2");
```

The problem with this is that it only works for the example above, if the tag would be named  without A-B, the inner content (X-Y) would be replaced instead.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example isn't working, its replacing only the hyphen in the tag.

Try this here

```
(<[^>]*)[a-zA-Z]\-[a-zA-Z]([^>]*)
```

and replace with `$1$2`

See it [online here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2um99)

Answer (score 0):

You could try `[^>\s]*` (match everything except `>` and whitespace) instead of `.*`, assuring you're still in the tag name.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just replace `[a-zA-Z]-[a-zA-Z]>` with `>`?